# Question migrated to other stackexchange site displays full name

Tags: feature-request, migration, user-accounts

I registered with my Gmail account and prefer to go by my initials. I recently had a Q moved to the Apple sister site and it automatically displayed my full name. Is there a way to prevent this behavior in the future?

Answer (score 5):

Your name is listed on [this page](http://stackexchange.com/users/fc19650a-ec36-400e-9965-25a4eb25b55b), if you can change it there or in your OpenID settings it won't reappear...

Comment: Tom, how do you change the name from the network user page?

Comment: I said "or", but it seems this has to be done in your OpenID settings. If not, click the **contact us** link in the bottom of the page and ask if they could do it for you. Include a link to your network user page...